# Convert 'Jul' to 'July' with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this response `Wed Jul 20 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Ora de vară a Europei de Est)` and I need to convert `Jul` to `July`. Is any chance to do it with moment.js?
If not, maybe simple way to convert it with vanilla JS.

Comment: By the way, you might consider _not using_ moment.js anymore, even the maintainers recommend to use `luxon` since it's inmutable:  https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
moment(new Date("Wed Jul 20 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300")).format('MMMM');
```

will return 'July';

You can find more there : https://momentjs.com/

Comment: you cant find this kind of expresion there. i searched a lot. thx

Answer (score 1):

JS `Date` objects now natively support [locale methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) for this sort of thing, which has the benefit of working for the whole world (which most regex-based or string-substitution based strategies for this type of problem will not):

```js
let d = new Date("Wed Jul 20 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300")

console.log(d.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' }))
```

Comment: because i'm from Romania, the output is 'iulie', not 'July', like i need

Answer (score 0):

You can get this using the format method of moment

- Using MMMM you can get **July**

Check this out [click here](https://momentjs.com/)

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```